# How to set default gcp service account to cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-composer

I have to run some python files(.py) in composer using bash operator, Those files present in compute engine but i'm not able to communicate with compute engine through composer. 
I think i need to add connection variable to communicate. Can any one help how to resolve this on.

```
def checkfile():
    file_path = '/root/sample-pyspark.py'

    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        print("File present")
        return True
    else:
        print("File not present")
        return False
with DAG('Demo_spark_job',
     default_args=default_args,
     schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
     ) as dag:

    print_hello = BashOperator(task_id='print_hello',
                           bash_command='echo "hello"')
    check_file = PythonOperator(task_id='check_file',
                             python_callable=checkfile)
    sample_spark_job = BashOperator(task_id='run_spark_job',
                     bash_command='sudo python /root/sample-pyspark.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

To have files (such as Python scripts) show up on your Cloud Composer Airflow workers, put them in your environment's associated GCS bucket. For example, if you put a file in `gs://my-composer-bucket/data/sample-pyspark.py` (i.e. the data directory), then you can access it at its mounted path:

```py
sample_spark_job = BashOperator(task_id='run_spark_job',
                 bash_command='sudo python /home/airflow/gcs/data/sample-pyspark.py')
```

You can read more about Composer's mapped directories on the [public documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_storage_name_bucket).

---

If I have misinterpreted your question above, and you actually want to run a Bash command on a different GCE instance, then you should look into using the [SSH operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py).

Comment: Thanks For your valuable input. It's solved half of my problem, Now check file is passed after placing file inside data/ folder . But now i'm getting python: can't open file '/home/airflow/gcs/data/sample-pyspark.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied. Can you please let me know why i'm getting permission denied error.

Comment: I would like to run bash command on same GCE but through composer i'm not able to connect GCE. Is there any way to connect GCE.

Comment: I found the solution to this issue. To resolve this we need allow access compute engine from composer. Then this issue will be resolved.